# Is there a word for "of or pertaining to"?

Tags: single-word-requests

So you have "ursine" which means "of or pertaining to bears", and you have "jentacular" which means "of or pertaining to breakfast". Is there a word that refers to this class of words, i.e. all words that mean "of or pertaining to X", where X is any arbitrary concept?

Comment: I hate to suggest it, but might that be as simple as suggested by http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/adj-forms.html

Comment: Note that unless 'pertaining to' is hopelessly broadened, the further sense of 'ursine' _resembling a bear_ is missed here. In Chambers 20th Century Dictionary, many adjectives had definitions starting 'of, like or pertaining to ...'. // Perhaps Robbie above is suggesting 'adjectival'. 'Attributive' is a reasonably close synonym when not on ELU.

Answer (score 1):

The OED settles for "of or pertaining to", listing the words as adjectives.

***Ursine*** is an adjectival form of "bear".

Some nouns have separate adjectival forms, others do not. Many animals fall into this category e.g. ***equine***, ***feline***, ***canine*** - horses, cats, dogs respectively. Many other natural things are also so served e.g. ***pulmonary*** - of or pertaining to lungs, ***cardiac*** - of or pertaining to the heart, ***marine*** - of or pertaining to the sea, ***arboreal*** - of or pertaining to trees  etc.

It may be possible to discover adjectival forms for many unlikely nouns, so I hesitate to quote examples of where there is none.

**However, if the OED does not quote a word for "of or pertaining to", I think you can safely assume there isn't one**.