# What is the name of this type of adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, terminology, derivational-morphology

Okay, I've been wondering this for a while. There's a specific type of adjective, and it seems to me that it should have a name, but I'm not sure if it does. It's the class of adjectives that can be defined as "of or having to do with [noun]." I'm adding a list at the bottom of this post, but one example would be [noun: space, adjective: spatial]. I've noticed that a lot of them end in -al, but not all of them. If anyone can give me a name or even point me toward any mention of these guys in a grammar book, I'd really appreciate it. Here's my list:

Rock, stone: Lithic

Title: titular, eponymous

Palace: palatial

Space: spatial

River, stream: fluvial

Profession: professional

Fantasy: fantastic

Gelatin: gelatinous

Mercury: mercurial

Time: temporal

Law: legal

Text: textual

Word? Lexicon? : Lexical

Example: exemplary

Worm: vermicular

Twin/pair: geminate?

Motif: motivic

Theme: thematic

Pivot: pivotal

Comment: Geminal for twins. It looks like it has been stolen by science though.

Comment: Closely related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404518/is-there-a-word-for-of-or-pertaining-to

Comment: For a [**proper noun**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/proper+noun), that is a [**proper adjective**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Proper-Adjectives.htm).

Comment: 'adjectival form'?

Comment: I tried but I can't think of a categorical response.